# The Strong Compactness Cardinal of $n$-th Order Logic

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, infinitary-logic

I was reading Kanamori's *The Higher Infinite*, when I came across the fact that for any extendible cardinal $\kappa$ and any $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa,\kappa}^n$-theory $T$, $Sat(T)\Leftrightarrow \forall t\subseteq T(|t|<\kappa\rightarrow Sat(t))$

I thought this was interesting, as any $\mathcal{L}_{\omega,\omega}^n$-theory $T$ (that is, normal $n+1$-th order logic) is also a $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa,\kappa}^n$-theory. This implies that, assuming an extendible cardinal exists, the strong compactness cardinal of $n+1$-th order logic exists and is at most the least extendible cardinal. In fact, the strong compactness cardinal of normal logic, the union of all $n$-th order logics for $0<n<\omega$, is at most the least extendible cardinal.

This brings up the following questions: **What is the consistency strength of asserting that $n$-th order logic has a strong compactness cardinal (for $n>1$)? If there is a strong compactness cardinal of $n$-th order logic, what large cardinal properties does it have?**

---

*EDIT:* I have since done some thinking on this problem, and realized the strong compactness cardinal of "normal logic" (as I called it) is at least the supremum of all strong compactness cardinals of all $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa,\kappa}^n$ for natural $n$ and cardinals $\kappa$. This of course means that, letting the strong compactness cardinal of normal logic be $\lambda$, the strong compactness cardinal of $\mathcal{L}_{\lambda,\lambda}^n$ is at most $\lambda$. Because of this, $\lambda$ must be extendible.

This fact combined with the fact the the strong compactness cardinal of normal logic is at most the least extendible cardinal shows that **the strong compactness cardinal of normal logic is in fact the least extendible cardinal.**

Comment: I wonder if they are basically very close, since to assert that an $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa,\kappa}^n$ theory $T$ has a model can be made in something like $\mathcal{L}_{\omega,\omega}^{n+1}$ as the assertion that there is a model and $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa,\kappa}$-truth predicate verifying every assertion of $T$ as true, and this now gets rid of the infinitary aspect of the theory.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins That may be. In any case, "normal logic" as I called it can express satisfiability of $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa,\kappa}^n$ theories, so the strong compactness cardinal of $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa,\kappa}^n$ is at most than that of normal logic for every $\kappa$ and $n$, and that is at most the least extendible cardinal.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins As you may see now, I have edited my question with the solution that the strong compactness cardinal of normal logic is the least extendible cardinal.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this question was already resolved, but here is a solution in the literature.

[Magidor showed](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02771565) (Theorem 4) that $\kappa$ is extendible iff $L^2_{\kappa\kappa}$ is $\kappa$-compact, and that $\kappa$ is the first extendible iff it is the minimal $\kappa$ such that $L^2_{\omega\omega}$ is $\kappa$-compact.

That is, although the usual statement is that $\kappa$ is extendible iff $L^n_{\kappa\kappa}$ is $\kappa$-compact for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, it is equivalent to the same statement about just $L^2_{\kappa\kappa}$.

Comment: By the way, this is also Theorem 23.4 in Kanamori.